# Specifying landing page on FORM auth

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee

Okay say that a user in a web-app can login in as `admin` or `user` from the same login page.

Based on the role the user will either be redirected to the admin page or the user page.

How do you specify such a thing in a web deployment descriptor ?

For Example-:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>USER</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name></realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/index.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/index.jsp?error=true</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

This protects all the resources under `user/` but which page does the user land to after login. There maybe multiple protected resources under `user/` so which one does the user land up in ?

Also how do I let both admin and user login from the same login portal and land the up in different pages ?

Comment: That's a decision you should be making during login

Comment: @kolossus Yes but how ? How do you specify a default landing page ?

Comment: Your index.jsp page should be a front controller. On successful login and redirect to index.jsp, you'll have code that examines the role of the login user, and based on that, redirect to the landing page for that role

Comment: @kolossus Yeah but are you saying that I should manually check the user role and identity ? Isn't that the job of the app server ?

Comment: The app server will do an initial authentication, just to be able to forward to index.jsp. It's your job, to then determine from there, where the user should be redirected to